# How should I save time in multiple API calls? [Python]

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

So I was just making a program that takes in text, splits them into a list each of n characters(here n=800) and then calls Microsoft Cognitive TTS api multiple times for decoded mp3 (as max limit of characters in single api call is 1000).

So for example, for about 16 API calls(due to the restriction obvio), time taken is about two and a half minutes to get the full response.
Is there a way by which I can restrict the whole time to something like under 25 secs maybe?

This probably could be resolved with multithreading/multiprocessing, but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried it doing once, but failed because the number of API calls is not fixed and totally depend on the length of text.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Just for clarification purposes,

- split_content_by_dot()  takes huge amount of text and divides them into n number of characters and returns a list of that divided text
- get_raw_wav() takes text as input and returns an decoded mp3 in which Microsoft's Cognitive API is used
- ```
  def this(text = ""):

      count = 0
      weird = ''
      if len(text)>950:
          x = split_content_by_dot(text, 800)
          #len(j) is approximately varies according to len of text
          for j in x:
              i = j.replace("<","").replace(">","")
              print i
              weird = weird + get_raw_wav(i)
              #calling of get_raw_wav(i) probably should be threaded
              count = count + 1
              print len(i)
          return_this = weird

      else:

          print 'yes'
          return_this = get_raw_wav(text)
      print count
      return return_this




  def get_raw_wav(text):
      key = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '__mykey__'}

      r = requests.post(url="https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken", headers=key)

      access_token = r.text

      headers = {"Content-type": "application/ssml+xml",
         "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat": "audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3",
         "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
         "X-Search-AppId": "__",
         "X-Search-ClientID": "__",
         "User-Agent": "TTSForPython"}
      body = "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-us'><voice xml:lang='en-CA' xml:gender='Female' name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-CA, HeatherRUS)'>" + text + "</voice></speak>"
      conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("speech.platform.bing.com")
      conn.request("POST", "/synthesize", body, headers)
      response = conn.getresponse()
      print(response.status, response.reason)
      data = response.read()
      encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
      conn.close()
      return encoded
  ```

Comment: Is `get_raw_wav`a part of some installed module or written by yourself? If it's a module, what is its name exactly? If it's your own code, put it here as well please.

Comment: @АндрейЧереваткин Thanks for your response! get_raw_wav() is a function that I've written.
I've added the get_raw_wav() code now.

Comment: Why didn't you use `requests` for the second HTTPS request? You can set timeout when making a request with `requests` http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Comment: @АндрейЧереваткин Yes that's fine, but won't solve the purpose because if an exception/error is raised that the time is exceeded, the mp3 would lose that amount of voice which eventually does not solve the purpose.